# Workout maximum amount of values (people) at a time from a list, codewars

Tags: list, tuples

As a historian, you wonder how many people ever lived in a specific area.

Given an amount of records as an array/vector/list of arrays/pairs/tuples representing the year of arrival/birth and departure/death from a given area, your task is to write a function that returns the maximum for that area and the year in which said maximum was achieved.

If more years have that maximum, just return the first one of them.

If you have both people entering and exiting the territory in the same year, consider that all new comers arrived/were born before anyone left/died for the sake of computing when the maximum was achieved

You will always be given at least one record of beginning/ending of a presence on the territory in valid format (ie: the first value will be lesser than or equal to the second).

This are examples of how it should look like:
year_max_people([(1978, 1978), (1969, 1998)]) == (2, 1978)
year_max_people([(1980, 2010), (1979, 1985), (1986, 1995), (1987, 2008)]) == (3, 1987)
year_max_people([(1980, 2010), (1979, 1985), (1986, 1995), (1981, 2000)] == (4, 1986)

Comment: can you show what you have been trying? this is not a platform for free coding

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Yes, please show us some of your code.  See here for reference on asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

## Finally got it, zip was key

```
 def year_max_people(records):
     year_max = max_people = current_people = 0
     running_records = (delta for record in records for delta in zip(record, (-1, 1)))
     for year, delta in sorted(running_records):
           current_people += delta
    
           if current_people < max_people:
                  year_max, max_people = year, current_people
     return -max_people, year_max
```

Comment: can you explain your answer with logic and concept used